# Customizing Ubuntu 18.04 for protecting data

Tags: 18.04, filesystem, customization, secure-boot, data-corruption

Is there any way to display and give access to only the browser on Ubuntu 18.04? I want the whole system to be protected and my use case anyway needs only the browser.

To give a clear picture, I want the users to log in and access only the browser with an abstraction of complete OS and filesystem. More like a customized IoT OS.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a user with no permissions, have the machine auto login and, if using a minimal install, simply have the browser and nothing else available.

Ubuntu has a tutorial for making a kiosk: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/secure-ubuntu-kiosk#0